# How to properly install LLVMLITE in windows 10?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to install the llvmlite in my windows 10, so i'm following the step-by-step from the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/llvmlite/latest/llvmlite.pdf):

```
You must have Visual Studio 2013 or later (the free “Express” edition is ok) in order to compile LLVM and llvmlite.
In addition, you must have cmake installed, and LLVM should have been built using cmake, in Release mode. Be
careful to use the right bitness (32- or 64-bit) for your Python installation.
```

So, i already have everything, and when i try to install with the command `python setup.py build`, the following error occurs:

```
Trying generator 'Visual Studio 12 2013'
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/G1745 IRON/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpvzyvoz/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/G1745 IRON/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpvzyvoz/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 140, in main
    main_win32()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 74, in main_win32
    generator = find_win32_generator()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 70, in find_win32_generator
    raise RuntimeError("No compatible cmake generator installed on this machine")
RuntimeError: No compatible cmake generator installed on this machine
error: command 'C:\\Python27\\python.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Searching a lot, i found that i should use the following command `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"`, but that's returning:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/llvmlite" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

I help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's a massive pain, I needed it for `numba` and it took ages to work out, I can't even remember what worked in the end. It _might_ have been through installing via the binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#llvmlite). Are you using this?

Comment: The sad part is that i'm stuck with Windows because of Firebird 1.5 :(. I'm going to check that, thanks!

Comment: The major problem of implementing Numba with windows is the redistribution... how can i automate the installation? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: As in, get the program to run on another computer?

Comment: Actually I have no idea, that's a good question. With the numerical stack in Python just being horrendous to get to work on Windows, I don't know if any of the `.exe` tools have any hope of solving it.

Comment: Yes. I think i prefer make it work the Firebird 1.5 in my Ubuntu (which is already impossible because there isn't the necessary files to make it work) than solving this... Thanks anyway!

Comment: What an awful position actually. I'm going to have a look around and see if I can find more info or potentially create an SO question (or you can). Honestly, you can get it to work in a few hours of firefighting so on that basis I'd say don't give up but then, if you have redistribution in mind, that might be a deal-breaker.

Comment: I won't give up at all, but this part (using Numba to improve the performance) is not necessary, it would be good to improve, but isn't necessary, so i'm going to let it go for now. Thanks, if you find something, let me know :).

Comment: The first 3 lines in configuration logs mean that either Visual Studio 12 (32 bit) is not installed on your machine or CMake isn't configured to use it. Create simple CMake project and try to build it using generator `Visual Studio 12`.

Answer (score 1):

i use windows 10, python 2 & python 3 and regularly use the link provided by @roganjosh to download & install pre-compiled binaries. i have just repeated this for a clean install, and yes, it works perfectly for llvmlite. for numba too.